# Google Apps for Business: Prevent users from reserving a resource for all-day events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

My company has 15 rooms. Each room is a separate resource.
End-users are sometimes not very bright.
Sometimes they reserve a room for an all-day event, and nobody else can reserve the room for the entire day.
Which is why I want users to NOT be able to reserve a room for an all-day event, but instead specify time range.
Is there a way to do this with Google script?

I was thinking, one way to do this might be to have a script run every time an event is created. And if it its location is in one of the rooms, and it's an all-day event, delete it and prompt the user to try again.

So here's the problem--there doesn't seem to be a way to create a trigger which fires upon event creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had almost the same situation in the school I work in. We have about 20 classrooms and some of them have a shared access (as calendar ressources). The problem is that some endusers make use of this without caring about others and without telling anybody... so I made a 'tracking script' that runs every hours and checks if an event has been added to the ressource calendar;  if it does, it sends me a mail so I can have a look and handle the situation.

After a few weeks, users became quite more careful on how they use the ressources since they know they are under surveillance ;-) so I don't need to delete the "bad events", they change it themselves !!

Anyway I guess the script I wrote could be modified quite easily to delete the events if they are "ALL DAY".

A few words to explain : the scripts keeps a log of all the events in a certain period of time (in ScriptProperties).  Every hour or so it checks if some event has been added or removed, it checks also who did it and if it is not a "white listed" user it sends me an email with a summary of what changed (formatted in a HTML table). It monitors all events between now and a fixed date (for me end of June ).

The main difficulty I had was to handle the events dropping out of the list because of the date... in a first version it sent a mail on each event endTime...
Now this version is working smoothly for me for a couple of month and although it is not perfect it's probably a good starting point for you (at least I hope so :-)

There is also a manual logging utility to get all events in a spreadsheet between any start/end date and another utility to get the calendar ID's for the script.

Here is a [public copy of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dExMUm1TSU1MZEpVelNYMG95TTFad1E&usp=sharing) so you can have a look

here is the full script ( a bit long, sorry about that)

```
  var nom = String(Session.getUser().getUserLoginId());
  var authorized = ['admin','webmaster','mary','william'];// define a list of 'authorized event creators'
  var owner = 'mail@xxx.yyy';// email to whom the email will be sent
  var collaborator = 'a collaborator email';// email of an additional collaborator (optional, see line 93)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();// this spreadsheet
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('master');
  var calList = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName('logger');
  var last = logsheet.getLastRow();
  var FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Manual test", functionName: "checkCal"},
                      {name: "Lauch autoTest", functionName: "manualcheck"},
                      {name: "delete created sheets", functionName: "delsheets"}
                     ];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.addMenu("Tracking utilities",menuEntries);//
//  Logger.log(FUS1)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('logger'));// start on logger page  
}

function manualcheck(){
    autoCheckAllCals();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    if(sheet.getSheets()>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[2]);// this works from the menu when ss is open
}
}

function autoCheckAllCals(){
    var eventarray = new Array();
    var logarray = new Array();
    var line = new Array();
    ss.setActiveSheet(logsheet)
    line.push('Events created by someone else','start ','end','location','Creator','Modification','event length','invited');
    eventarray.push(line);
    var today =  new Date(); // maintenant
    var startDate = new Date(today.getTime()-120*60*1000);// 2h before now
    var endDate = new Date("june 30, 2013 23:59:00"); // choice every year
    var sendMail = true    
    var mailSent = false
    logsheet.insertRowAfter(last)
    var sheetName = "Control from "+ Utilities.formatDate(startDate, FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")
      + "-to-" + Utilities.formatDate(endDate, FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")  
  for(nn=0;nn<calList.length;++nn){
    var calName = calList[nn][0];
    var calId = calList[nn][1];   
// Logger.log(calList)   
// Logger.log(startDate+'  |  '+endDate)   
// Logger.log(calName+' | '+calId)
    var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId)
        var events = Calendar.getEvents(startDate , endDate);
    if (events[0]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      if(events[i].getTitle().match('week nr')=='week nr'){continue};// this condition to ignore week numbers that we add in all calendars.... might be anything else that should be ignored
      var skip = false
      for(var aaa in authorized){
//Logger.log(events[i].getCreators())
      if(events[i].getCreators().join().match(authorized[aaa])==authorized[aaa]){skip=true;continue};// check if creator is in the 'authorized' list
        }
        if(skip){continue}
//Logger.log(events[i].getStartTime()+'   '+events[i].getEndTime());      
      if(events[i].getStartTime()<today||events[i].getEndTime()<today){Logger.log('condition < today = true '
         +events[i].getTitle()+' start='+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm")+' end='+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));sendMail=false;continue}
// if condition = true update script properties so it won't generate an alert when finishing
      var line = new Array();
      var logline = new Array();
      FUS1=events[i].getStartTime().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
      line.push(calName +' : '+events[i].getTitle());
      logline.push(calName +' : '+events[i].getTitle()+'|');
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      logline.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm")+'|');
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      line.push(events[i].getLocation());      
      line.push(events[i].getCreators().join());
      logline.push(events[i].getCreators().join()+'∏');
      line.push('on '+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getLastUpdated(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy"))
      line.push(((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime()) / 3600000)+' hours');
      var invitelist='';
      var list = events[i].getGuestList()
          for(n=0;n<list.length;++n){invitelist+=list[n].getName()+', '}
      line.push(invitelist)
      eventarray.push(line);
      logarray.push(logline)
    }
//    Logger.log(logarray)
    }    
}
      if(eventarray.length>1){     
  var message = logarray.toString().replace(/,/g,'')
  var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest')
      if(formertest!=message){
Logger.log('changement ...')        
  var html = createMsg(message)
  if(sendMail){
      MailApp.sendEmail(owner,'Events created by someone in your calendar', "", {"htmlBody" : html});
//      MailApp.sendEmail(collaborator,'Events created by someone in your calendar', "", {"htmlBody" : html});// supprimer ou commenter cette ligne si nécessaire
Logger.log('send mail')
mailSent = true
  }
    ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': message}, true);   
      try{ 
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName,2);
      }catch(error){
        FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
        var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName+' - '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss"),2);
        }
    newsheet.getRange(1,1,eventarray.length,eventarray[0].length).setValues(eventarray);
    newsheet.getRange(1,1,1,eventarray[0].length).setBackgroundColor('#ffffcc');
    newsheet.setColumnWidth(1, 350).setColumnWidth(2, 150).setColumnWidth(3, 150).setColumnWidth(4, 150).setColumnWidth(5, 150).setColumnWidth(6, 105).setColumnWidth(7, 95).setColumnWidth(8, 450);
    newsheet.setFrozenRows(1)
}
    ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': message}, true);    // even if no mail, write to script properties       
      }
  FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
  var logmsg = 'Auto test launched on '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1,"MMM-dd-yy @ HH:mm");
  if (mailSent){logmsg+=" - mail sent"}else{logmsg+=" - no alert"}
   logsheet.getRange(last+1,1).setValue(logmsg);
}


function createMsg(logarray){
  var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest');
  if(!formertest){return}
  var testitems = formertest.split('∏');
  var items = logarray.split('∏');
  if(items.length>testitems.length){
  var color='#CCFFCC'
  if(testitems.toString().indexOf(items[0])==-1){color='#FFBBBB'}
    var html = " Digest of Events created by someone else :<B> new events in RED </B><BR><BR><TABLE border = 1 cellpadding = 5><EVENTS></table>"    
  var table = "<tr valign='top' bgcolor='"+color+"' cellpadding=5>"
      color='#CCFFCC'
      for(zz=0;zz<items.length-1;++zz){
//  Logger.log(testitems.toString().indexOf(items[zz]))  
        var subitems = items[zz].split('|')
        if(testitems.toString().indexOf(items[zz+1])==-1){color='#FFBBBB'}
        for(tt=0;tt<subitems.length;++tt){
         table+= '<td>'+subitems[tt]+'</td>'
    }
        table+="</tr><tr valign='top' bgcolor='"+color+"' cellpadding=5>"   
        color='#CCFFCC'
            }
        table+='</tr>'
  var msghtml = html.replace("<EVENTS>",table) 
//    Logger.log(msghtml)
      return msghtml
}else{
  var color='#FFBBBB'
  if(items.toString().indexOf(testitems[0])==-1){color='#FFBBBB'}
  var html = "One (or more) event removed <B>in RED</B> as shown below<BR><BR><TABLE border = 1 cellpadding = 5 bgcolor='"+color+"'><EVENTS></table>"    
  var table = "<tr valign='top' bgcolor='"+color+"' cellpadding=5>"
      for(zz=0;zz<items.length;++zz){
//  Logger.log(testitems.toString().indexOf(items[zz]))  
        var subitems = testitems[zz].split('|')
        if(items.toString().indexOf(testitems[zz])==-1){
        for(tt=0;tt<subitems.length;++tt){
         table+= '<td>'+subitems[tt]+'</td>'
    }
        }
        table+="</tr>"
            }
        table+='</tr>'
  var msghtml = html.replace("<EVENTS>",table) 
//    Logger.log(msghtml)
      return msghtml
}
}


function checkCalendars(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var calendar_name = e.parameter.calendar;
  var startDate = new Date(e.parameter.start);
  var endDate = new Date(e.parameter.end);
  var calList = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
   for(nn=0;nn<calList.length;++nn){
     if(calList[nn][0]==calendar_name){var CalId = calList[nn][1];break}
   }
  var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalId)
//   
  var sheetName = calendar_name + "-from-" + Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.start, FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")
      + "-to-" + Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.end, FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")  
//
  var events = Calendar.getEvents(startDate , endDate);
  if (events[0]) {
    logsheet.getRange(last+1,1).setValue('Manual test launched on '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1,"MMM-dd-yy"));
    ss.setActiveSheet(logsheet)
    var eventarray = new Array();
    var line = new Array();
    line.push('Calendar Name : '+calendar_name,'start ','end','Localisation','created by','Modification','event length','invited');
    eventarray.push(line);
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      if(events[i].getTitle().match('week')=='week'){continue}
      line = new Array();
      line.push(events[i].getTitle());
      FUS1=events[i].getStartTime().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      line.push(events[i].getLocation());      
      line.push(events[i].getCreators().join());
      line.push('on '+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getLastUpdated(), FUS1, "MMM-dd-yy"))
      line.push((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime()) / 3600000);
      var invitelist='';
      var list = events[i].getGuestList()
          for(nn=0;nn<list.length;++nn){invitelist+=list[nn].getName()+', '}
      line.push(invitelist)
      eventarray.push(line);
    }
    Logger.log(eventarray)
      try{ 
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName,2);
      }catch(error){
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName+'-'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH-mm-ss"),2)
        }
    newsheet.getRange(1,1,eventarray.length,eventarray[0].length).setValues(eventarray);
    newsheet.getRange(1,1,1,eventarray[0].length).setBackgroundColor('#ffffcc');
    newsheet.setColumnWidth(1, 350).setColumnWidth(2, 150).setColumnWidth(3, 150).setColumnWidth(4, 150).setColumnWidth(5, 150).setColumnWidth(6, 105).setColumnWidth(7, 95).setColumnWidth(8, 450);
    newsheet.setFrozenRows(1)
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[2]);// envoie sur la page créée
  } else {
    var startstring = Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.start, FUS1, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
    var endstring = Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.end, FUS1, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Browser.msgBox('no event between ' + startstring + ' and ' + endstring +' in your calendar :'+calendar_name);
  }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;  
}


function checkCal() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Calendar Tracking");
  app.setHeight(265).setWidth(400);
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel("Name of the Calendar:"));
  var list = app.createListBox();
  list.setName('calendar');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
  for (var i = 0; i < calList.length; i++) {
    list.addItem(calList[i][0]);
  }
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Start Date :'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setId("start").setValue(new Date()));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('End Date :'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createDateBox().setId("end").setValue(new Date(new Date().getTime()+30*86400000)));
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);
  var button = app.createButton('Start Checking & report');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('checkCalendars');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  var clock = app.createImage('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/211279/Time-change-clock_animated_TR80.gif', 0, 0, 82, 82).setId('clock').setVisible(false);
  var clockHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(clock).setVisible(true);
  button.addClickHandler(clockHandler)
  panel.add(button).add(clock);
  app.add(panel);
  doc.show(app);
}

function delsheets(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numbofsheet=ss.getNumSheets();// check how many sheets in the spreadsheet
    for (pa=numbofsheet-1;pa>0;--pa){ 
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[pa]);
      if(ss.getSheets()[pa].getSheetName()!='logger'&&ss.getSheets()[pa].getSheetName()!='master'){
      var newSheet = ss.deleteActiveSheet(); // delete sheets begining with the last one
      Utilities.sleep(400);
    }
    }
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);// return to first sheet as active sheet (useful in 'list' function)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }

// This small function is to get the list of calendar names & Ids that you have access to, please edit the master sheet to keep only the ones you want to monitor (without empty rows).
function Callist(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('master')
  sh.getDataRange().clearContent();                      
  var list = new Array();
  var store = new Array();
  list = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()
    for (n=0;n<list.length;++n){
      var name = list[n].getName() ;                     
      var id = list[n].getId() ;                     
        store.push( [name,id])
    }        
  sh.getRange(1,1,store.length,store[0].length).setValues(store);  
}
```